# Using sql SUM in join tables to get a certain result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 4 tables like these:

QUESTIONS:

```
+----+------------+
| id |   title    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Question A |
|  2 | Question B |
|  3 | Question C |
|  4 | Question D |
|  5 | Question E |
|  6 | Question F |
|  7 | Question G |
|  8 | Question H |
|  9 | Question J |
| 10 | Question K |
+----+------------+
```

ANSWERED_QUESTIONS

```
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+
| ID | value  | question_id | answer_id |
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 | YES    |           1 |         1 |
|  2 | NO     |           2 |         1 |
|  3 | NO     |           3 |         1 |
|  4 | YES    |           4 |         1 |
|  5 | YES    |           5 |         1 |
|  6 | YES    |           6 |         1 |
|  7 | YES    |           7 |         1 |
|  8 | NO     |           8 |         1 |
|  9 | YES    |           9 |         1 |
| 10 | NO     |          10 |         1 |
| 11 | NO     |           1 |         2 |
| 12 | YES    |           2 |         2 |
| 13 | YES    |           3 |         2 |
| 14 | YES    |           4 |         2 |
| 15 | YES    |           5 |         2 |
| 16 | YES    |           6 |         2 |
| 17 | YES    |           7 |         2 |
| 18 | YES    |           8 |         2 |
| 19 | NO     |           9 |         2 |
| 20 | YES    |          10 |         2 |
+----+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

ANSWERS

```
+----+-----------+----------+-------------+
| ID | total_yes | total_no | hospital_id |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 |         6 |        4 |           1 |
|  2 |         8 |        2 |           2 |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

HOSPITALS

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Hospital A |
|  2 | Hospital B |
|  3 | Hospital C |
+----+------------+
```

I want to get the total_yes and total_no of each questions answered by hospital, eg

FINAL_TABLE

```
+----+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id |  Question  | Total Yes | Total No | Hospital_id |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | Question A |         1 |        1 |           1 |
|  2 | Question B |         1 |        1 |           1 |
|  3 | Question C |         1 |        1 |           1 |
|  4 | Question D |         2 |        0 |           1 |
+----+------------+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

I need to create a chart with this information, where the user wil put the Hospital name and the questions details wil be showed

How can i do this?

Im using Rails with postgres database

EDIT 1

QUESTION MODEL

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :answered_questions, inverse_of: :question
    has_many :answers, through: :answered_questions


    has_attached_file :image, :storage => :cloudinary, :path => ':id/:style/:filename', styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

    validates_presence_of :title, :campaign

    # validates_associated :campaign

    def image_url
        image.url(:thumb)
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you paste your `Question` model here?

Comment: Done. I edited to past my question model

Comment: Wrote a possible answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Question.joins(:answers).select('title, total_yes, total_no, hospital_id'). distinct
```

This is how I get your task. Keep me posted in case it doesn't work or it's invalid solution, I will update and try to help.

@Eduardorph Or does total_yes and total_no are specific for hospital and doesn't take into account question? Then why you store it in answers table where there should be a lot of records for each hospital and your total columns will be just a duplication for each similar hospital id?

You have serious issues in your DB design. I am 95% sure that question_answers and answer should be squashed in a single table.

Also I don't like your `total_yes` columns. You should either think about counter_cache solution or calculate it every time with SQL. Right now I am sure this code will turn into future bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming answer_id will always be equal to hospital_id, this would be the query you might need:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
     SELECT 
        aq.question_id,
        q.title,
        COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE value='YES') as total_yes,
        COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE value='NO') as total_no,answer_id
     FROM answered_questions aq,questions q
     WHERE aq.question_id = q.id
     GROUP BY ROLLUP(question_id,title,answer_id)
    )data_set
WHERE answer_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY answer_id,question_id
```